# How to replace a large substring in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, substitution

Have a file containing multiple lines. But in some lines, there's a large substring need to be sorted. Now I got the substring and sorted substring, both stored as variables. Is there a way to replace the large substring?

i have tried **sed -i "s?$subStr?$sortSub?" file** but sed raised *argument list too long* error. didn't find relevant solutions. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried writing `"s?$subStr?$sortSub?"` to a file named myscript.sed, then using `sed -i -f myscript.sed file`? See also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-script-overview.html

Comment: @NickODell Just tried, only **s?$subStr?$sortSub?** written in the sed file is ok. It works flawlessly. Thank you so much Nick!

Comment: @NickODell Sorry about the early reply. No error was raised then, but when I test it with simle string, the substring cannot be replaced. Because I think in the sed file, variables cannot be identified. So no replacement was done.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284170/replace-a-long-string-with-the-sed-command-argument-list-too-long-error The first answer solves the problem, similar to you method with the option "-f", but it reads from stdin so it expands the variable before replacement. Thanks for your help anyway! @NickODell

Comment: `( mapfile -d '' data <file; printf '%s' "${data//"$subStr"/"$sortSub"}" >file )`